# inf2cat for Win10 driver signing

Tags: windows, usbserial

I am using Microsoft's **usbser.sys** driver to communicate with custom hardware using a serial interface emulation via USB.

Since Win 8.1 I have to sign the driver. 
I the process, I used this command:

```
Inf2Cat /driver:"c:\path_to_driver" /os:8_X64,8_X86,Server8_X64,Server2008R2_X64,7_X64,7_X86,Server2008_X64,Server2008_X86,Vista_X64,Vista_X86,Server2003_X64,Server2003_X86,XP_X64,XP_X86,2000
```

Everything worked great. However, things do not work under Windows 10.

I get: "Adding the driver package failed: Invalid INF passed as parameter. (...) Driver pre-installation has failed with error #2 ()"

I think that I need to add Windows 10 to the list of supported os's. How can I do this? Windows10 is not a valid value.

I guess that I will have to install a more up to date version of Inf2Cat. Does anybody know where I can find one that supports Windows10?
Or is there a different way to create cat files from inf files for Windows 10?

I installed WindowsKits8.1 under Win10, but there is no Inf2Cat.exe file. There is a makecat.exe file however. Is this the way to go? Where do I get a .cdf-file for Microsoft's usbser.sys driver?

Comment: I have found an answer to my own question, please see below

Answer (score 11):

Ok, this is me *answering my own question*:

I simply looked in the wrong folder. The inf2cat is still available for Windows 10.

I now do

`cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86"
Inf2Cat.exe /driver:"c:\path\to\driver" /os:8_X64,8_X86,Server8_X64,Server2008R2_X64,7_X64,7_X86,Server2008_X64,Server2008_X86,Vista_X64,Vista_X86,Server2003_X64,Server2003_X86,XP_X64,XP_X86,2000,10_X86,10_X64,Server10_X64`

Please note that you cannot specify the path+filename of your *.inf file, but you need to specify the directory path only. That's the */driver:"c:\path\to\driver"* above, where driver is a directory and *not* and .inf file.

Comment: If you are building with Visual Studio, you are better off using the environment variable `$(Inf2CatToolPath)`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply You must download an Windows Driver Kit(WDK)
[Download WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)